# iPhone, float textures

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, floating-point, textures

I need to have GL_**RGBA32F** as internal format, but i do not get this in OpenGL ES implementation. Instead of this i get only **GL_FLOAT** as a texture data type. The **OES_texture_float** spec has nothing to say what's inside. So i do not know, whether my texture data will be normalized to [0, 1] or not. Basically i need to store in texture unclamped texture data regardless it's float or integer value. How i can get not normalized data inside my texture?

Comment: If you've found an answer, please be kind enough to post it as an answer in case others have a similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, OpenGL ES treats the parameters to glTex(Sub)Image* differently from desktop OpenGL.

In desktop OpenGL, what defines the actual format of the texture is the *internalformat*. In GL ES 2.0, it is the *format* and *type* values that define this. So if you upload a (GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE) texture, that's the equivalent of using GL_RGBA8 as the internal format.

What this means is that, if you want a floating-point texture, you use (GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT) as the *format* and *type* parameters. It's a pointless inconsistency between the two specifications.