# OpenGL program port to Android OpenGL ES2.0

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I have a OpenGL program on desktop, now I am going to port to Android.

I used one API on desktop version is:

```
// Allocate graphics memory.
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA,
            GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

but in OpenGL ES2.0, I can only use the API like this:

```
// Allocate graphics memory.
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

So the internal format changed from GL_RGBA32F to GL_RGB, and type from GL_FLOAT to GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, and in my shaders, I calculate the fragment colour in float values, I can see the result image got some problem, e.g, the white color pixels become green color.

I want to know is this problem because of the glTextImage2D in OpenGL ES2.0 not supporting float type?

Comment: Check out these posts mate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313224/iphone-float-textures
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675479/android-opengl-es-2-0-can-a-gl-float-texture-be-assigned-to-a-fbo-as-a-color-a

Comment: @JohnRiselvato so I should use `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);` in openGL ES2.0? I tried, but it will generate 'invalid operation' error....  any idea for this?

Comment: No, don't do that. In OpenGL ES it is invalid to use a different pixel transfer format than the internal format.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman what if I use `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);`?  I tried, but when I bind this texture to FBO `glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textID, 0);` and check the framebuffer status, it shows error.  it seems I cannot use GL_FLOAT type for glTextImage2D() method.

Comment: No, like I said you cannot use a different type for the pixel transfer format in OpenGL ES. This would require the driver to do floating-point to fixed-point data conversion, which was eliminated from OpenGL ES - *only* desktop OpenGL allows this. From the specification: ***internalformat must match format. No conversion between formats is supported during texture image processing. type may be used as a hint to specify how much precision is desired, but a GL implementation may choose to store the texture array at any internal resolution it chooses.***